# Bug in Directly Mapped Cache Simulator C++

Tags: c++, caching, vector

disclaimer: this is a long one, so please bear with me boys and girls.

Hey guys. I am making a Directly Mapped cache simulator with write-back policy.
I am getting a slight error in my code. Allow me to show you the code and at the bottom I will explain the error.

Input & output files that produce partial incorrect output:

```
input:
read 0x02000006
read 0x04000004
write 0x02000007
read 0x06000004
write 0x01000001
read 0x01000002
write 0x02000000
read 0x06000007
read 0x05000003
write 0x02000001
write 0x03000000
write 0x04000002
read 0x03000004
read 0x01000003
read 0x03000005
write 0x04000004
read 0x04000007
write 0x05000003
read 0x02000000
write 0x02000003
read 0x03000002
read 0x00700002
read 0x02000005
write 0x01000001
read 0x01000006
write 0x01000005
write 0x07000006
write 0x02000003
read 0x03000002
read 0x01000000
read 0x03000001
read 0x01000007



my output:
1024    8       DM  0.00    256     104     1
1024    16      DM  0.00    512     416     1
1024    32      DM  0.00    1024    832     1
1024    128     DM  0.00    4096    3328    1



what output should be:
1024    8   DM  0.16    216     96      1
1024    16  DM  0.16    432     192     1
1024    32  DM  0.16    864     384     1
1024    128 DM  0.16    3456    1536    1
```

Header:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct input
{
    bool dirtyBit;
    int statusBit; //0 not in cache, 1 in cache
    bool writeStatus; //write = 1 read = 0
    int address;
};

class Cache
{

public:
    
    vector<input> dataBase;
    Cache(string);
    ~Cache();

    void DirectMapped(int, int);

};
```

Implementation File:

```
#include "Header.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

Cache::Cache(string infile)
{
    ifstream in(infile);
    string readWriteStatus;
    int Addr;
    while (in >> readWriteStatus >> hex >> Addr)
    {
        input contents;
        if (readWriteStatus == "read")
            contents.writeStatus = false;
        else if (readWriteStatus == "write")
            contents.writeStatus = true;
        contents.address = Addr;
        contents.dirtyBit = false;
        contents.statusBit = 0;
        dataBase.push_back(contents);
    }
}

Cache::~Cache(){}

void Cache::DirectMapped(int cacheSize, int blockSize)
{
    //initial stats needed
    int blockCount = cacheSize/blockSize;
    //clear out the cache
    for (int i = 0; i < dataBase.size(); i++)
        dataBase[i].statusBit = 0;
    int hit = 0;
    int MtoCBytes = 0;
    int CtoMBytes = 0;
    int apple=0;
    for (int x = 0; x < dataBase.size(); x++)
    {
        int blockIndex = (dataBase[x].address/blockSize)%blockCount;
        int blockOffset = (dataBase[x].address)%blockSize;
        int tag = dataBase[x].address/cacheSize;

        if(dataBase[x].statusBit == 1)
            hit++;
        else
        {
            if(dataBase[x].dirtyBit == true)
                CtoMBytes +=blockSize;
            dataBase[x].statusBit == 1;
            MtoCBytes += blockSize;
        }
        if (dataBase[x].writeStatus == true && dataBase[x].writeStatus == true)
            dataBase[x].dirtyBit = true;

    }
    for (int y = 0; y < dataBase.size(); y++)
    {
        if (dataBase[y].dirtyBit == true)
            CtoMBytes +=blockSize;
    }
    float hitRatio = hit/dataBase.size();
    cout << cacheSize << " " << blockSize << " DM ";
    cout << setiosflags(ios::fixed|ios::showpoint) << setprecision(2) << hitRatio << " "; 
    cout << MtoCBytes << " " << CtoMBytes << " 1" << endl;
}
```

Main:

```
#include "Header.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string inputfile = "C:/Users/Christopher/Downloads/test1";
    string infile = inputfile.append(".trace");
    Cache myCache(infile);

    // Parse Command Line Argument
//    if(argc != 2)
//        cout << "ERROR: Improper Number of Arguments" << endl;
//    else
//    {
       int i = 1024;
            for(int j = 8; j <= 128; j= j*2)
            {
                myCache.DirectMapped(i,j);
                if (j==32)
                    j=j*2;
            }
        
        system ( "pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Okay, so the issue with this is, as you can see, there the output is messed up. If you look at the end of the implantation file, you can seethe areas that are messed up are Hit Ratio, Memory to Cache, and Cache to Memory.

I know how cache works, I know how write-policy works, I know how it all works. What I don't know is why this code wont work. I have debugged it for while now with no such luck.

That being said, I'm certian someone on here could help me out. Im confident that the issue lies in the method titled DirectMapped. The code if you set it up runs as is on here.
Please help me out, I will really appreciate it.

Comment: This looks like a copy-paste mistake: `if (dataBase[x].writeStatus == true && dataBase[x].writeStatus == true)`.

Comment: Saw that earlier and thought I removed it. Guess not. But still, removing that shouldnt change my current stats that are incorrect. :/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line

```
float hitRatio = hit/dataBase.size();
```

`hit` is an `int`, `database.size()` is an `int`, then the result will be an `int`.
Change to this,

```
float hitRatio = ((float)hit)/dataBase.size();
```

to see if there is anything different.

Comment: when I made the change it didnt change anything  unfortunately, output is still incorrect. The reason I used a float there was because I need my output to be in decimal places

Comment: Well, could it display a float number, or just an **0.00**

Comment: I made the change and unfortunately it didnt work :/

Comment: It didn't work in which way? About the displayed result? Post your result so that I can examine it further.

Comment: using this line: float hitRatio = ((float)hit)/((float)dataBase.size()); I get an answer of 0.00

But using this line: float hitRatio = ((float)hit)/((float)dataBase.size()); I get an answer of 0 

And using this line: float hitRatio = ((float)hit)/dataBase.size(); I get a number of 0

Comment: Then, the 2 result are the same and not what you're expecting. I suggest that you check your algorithm again.

Comment: thats the plan, reluctantly. hah